# Solve linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on some practice linear algebra problems but I am not understanding how the answers where gotten for the following problem.

Problem:
find all values of $a$ for which the resulting linear system has (a) no solution, (b) a unique solution, and (c) infinitely many solutions.

\begin{cases} x + y - z =2\\ x + 2y + z = 3 \\ x + y + (a^2 -5)z = a \end{cases}

Answer:

(a) $a= -2,\;$ (b) $\;a\neq \pm2,\;$ (c) $a=2$

I can't for the life figure how they got the answer in the book. I only got as far as the row echelon matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -1 & 2\\0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & a^2 - 4 & a-2\end{bmatrix}$

Can anyone recommend an approach for solving the problem.

Comment: What are $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @Bernard thats what I am wondering.  It is from the text Introductory Linear Algebra with applications 7th edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the matrix in something approaching row echelon form is definitely the right way to go, and you are nearly done once you have it. Unfortunately I think you did your final row operation incorrectly; my row echelon form matrix looks like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -1 & 2\\0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & a^2-4 & a-2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is this enough to show you the way?

Comment: I think I get where the a^2 - 4 gives the + or - 2.  The not equal is because its a quadratic equation?

Comment: @user1238097 The distinction has to come from how we interpret each row of this augmented matrix; when $a=-2$, the final row reads as $[0,0,0,-4]$, which in the language of equations reads $0=-4$. Of course, it cannot be that $0=-4$, and that tells us the system of equations we started with was inconsistent (that it had no solutions). Instead, if $a=2$, the final row is $[0,0,0,0]$, which reads $0=0$, which is true but uninformative. This means there is a free variable, and we will have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @user1238097 When $a\neq \pm 2$, what happens? We could go from row echelon form to reduced row echelon form (since we know we can divide by $a^2-4$ safely), and we will end up with an identity matrix in the left hand portion of the augmented matrix, which means there is a unique solution.

Comment: oh wow that makes a lot of sense definitely.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

A non-homogeneous linear system has solutions if and only if the matrix of the homogeneous side and the augmented matrix have the same rank. Furthermore, this rank is the codimension of the affine space of solutions.

Thus here, there is a unique solution if and only if the matrix $\;\smash{\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\ 1&2&1\\1&1&a^2-5\end{bmatrix}}$ has rank $3$. You can obtain its rank with row reduction.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I need to go back to look at homogenous systems section in the book.

Answer (score 2):

The standard start:

The matrix is

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 1 & a^2-5 & a
\end{bmatrix}
$

The 3x3 determinant  is
$2(a^2-5)+1-1-(1+(a^2-5)-2)
=a^2-4
$
so,
if $a^2 \ne 4$,
there is a unique solution.

Comment: So I don't have to the linear equations to solve this wow.

Comment: I take issue with this answer, as it is a bit sloppy; you cannot take the determinant of a $3\times 4$ matrix. The approach is nice, but you should clean up your explanation.

Comment: @ImNotTheGuy it is definitely a bit more confusing.

Comment: Non-square matrices don't have a determinant.

Comment: OK - I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

note: in the original version of the question the answer for part b was subtuly wrong, it should say $a \neq \pm 2$

I would start by getting rid of x by subtracting one of the cases (I went for the first one) from the other two.

$$ (2y + z)-(y-z) = 3 - 2 $$
$$ (y + (a^2 -5)z) - (y-z) = a - 2 $$

Multiplying out and simplifying.

$$ y + 2z = 1 $$

$$ (a^2 -4)z = a - 2 $$

So how do you solve an equation like that? you would want to divide it through by $(a^2 -4)$ but it is only valid to do that if $(a^2 -4) \neq 0$. Some elementary knowlage of quadratics tells us that $(a^2 -4) \neq 0$ when $a \neq \pm 2$. Therefore when $a \neq \pm 2$ our equation gives a single value for z which in turn gives a single value for y which in turn gives a single value for x.

Ok what about when $a = \pm 2$ well since we only have to cases left we can just substitute them in.

$$ 0z = -2 - 2 = -4 $$

$$ 0z = 2 - 2 = 0 $$

The first equation clearly has no soloutions, the second clearly has an infinite soloution set.

Comment: fixed that error.

Comment: I am still in the intro portion of the course, but is this method only possible if you know determinants?

Comment: The method I used does not involve calculating or knowing about determinants, It's just the elimination method of solving simultaneous equations (which turned out to be unusually simple in this case, because we didn't have to do any scaling before we could perform elimination of x and because y happened to drop out of the third equation at the same time as x) combined with being mindful of the possibility of division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

our equations: (a^2 means a * a)

x+y−z=2

x+2y+z=3

x+y+(a^2−5)z=a

general equation form:

a1*x+b1*y+c1*z = d1

a2*x+b2*y+c2*z = d2

a3*x+b3*y+c3*z = d3

matrix A:

a1 b1 c1

a2 b2 c2

a3 b3 c3

matrix B:

d1 b1 c1

d2 b2 c2

d2 b3 c3

matrix C:

a1 d1 c1

a2 d2 c2

a3 d3 c3

matrix D:

a1 b1 d1

a2 b2 d2

a3 b3 d3

x = det(B) / det(A);

y = det(C) / det(A);

z = det(D) / det(A)

matrix A general format:

a11 a12 a13

a21 a22 a23

a31 a32 a33

det(A) = a11*a22*a33 + a12*a23*a31 + a13*a21*32 - a13*a22*a31 - a12*a21*a33 - a11*a23*a32

det(B) = d1*b2*c3 + b1*c2*d3 + c1*d2*b3 - c1*b2*d3 - b1*d2*c3 - d1*c2*b3

det(C) = a1*d2*c3 + d1*c2*a3 + c1*a2*d3 - c1*d2*a3 - d1*a2*c3 - a1*c2*d3

det(D) = a1*b2*d3 + b1*d2*a3+ d1*a2*b3 - d1*b2*a3- b1*a2*d3 - a1*d2*b3

assuming if my math below is correct, we get:

det(A) = a^2 - 4

det(B) = a^2+3a-10

det(C) = a^2-2a

det(D) = a - 2

x = (a^2+3a-10) / (a^2 - 4)

y = (a^2+3a-10) / (a^2 - 4)

z = (a-2)/(a^2 - 4)

If a^2 = 4, then the equation has no solution b/c we can't divide by zero

So, we can't have a = -2 or a = 2

Otherwise, the equation has the unique solution.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)